# Azure AD B2C Application API not available as Permission

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c) to register a frontend and backend application in Azure AD B2C. However, I'm stuck at step 11 under [Configure the Frontend Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c#configure-the-frontend-application).  My applications aren't appearing as available under **My APIs**.

Backend App with test API exposed:

[image: backend]

Fronted app trying to register permission

[image: frontend]

What do I need to do to make my application available as API Permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created **Backend App** and Exposed an API same as you by adding `api.test` scope:

[image]

Now, I tried to **add the permission in the Frontend** and faced the same issue:

[image]

> Note that, these exposed API permissions will appear under **APIs my organization uses** if you are not owner of that App as *@bolt-io* mentioned.

Hence, to add the permission in the Frontend, click on **“APIs my organization uses”** and search the `Test API Exposure` App:

[image]

**I am able to add the permission in frontend successfully:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are not listed in the 'Owners' blade of the `Test API Exposure` app registration it will not appear in 'My APIs'.

Switch to the tab 'APIs my organization uses' and it should be visible.